# Unable to connect to web server '%server name%' after add EnableRetryOnFailure

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-8.0

I have this code and it works fine. But if I add **`o => o.EnableRetryOnFailure()`** I get an error:
Unable to connect to web server '**%server name%**'

[image]

```
    services.AddDbContextFactory<AsterixDBContext>(
    options =>
        options.UseMySql(connectionAsterixDBString, 
        ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionAsterixDBString)
        //, o => o.EnableRetryOnFailure() <-- Add this and error
    ),
    ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
```

Connection string:

> Server=%severname%;Database=asterix-dev;Uid=asterix;Pwd=%password%;default command timeout=300

Database is 11.0.4-mariadb.

Comment: Have you tried without `AutoDetect`? Have you used `Pomelo` driver or buggy Oracles's one?

Comment: I use Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 8.0.1. Try this, not working: 
`var serVer = ServerVersion.Parse("11.0.4-mariadb");
services.AddDbContextFactory<AsterixDBContext>(options =>
    options.UseMySql(connectionAsterixDBString
    , serVer //.AutoDetect(connectionAsterixDBString)
    , o => o.EnableRetryOnFailure()
    ),
    ServiceLifetime.Singleton);`